# radiobutton.value is nothing on bindingsource.endedit

Tags: vb.net, radio-button

ok, here's the issue, I set a radiobutton.value to true. when I go to save and perform bindingsource.endedit. radiobutton.value is then nothing. any ideas as to what could cause this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean by radiobutton.value? it's the checked property which is used.
You would like to try this

before performing bindingsource.endedit

```
radiobutton.checked = true
```

after performing the edit

```
radiobuttoon.checked = false
```